# can I give src="D:\OnlinePjct\videos\movie.mp4" in <video> tag?

Tags: html

It was working when i give src="serial.mp4" which is in the same folder of netbeans but not when i give path of C drive.`<video src="D:\OnlinePjct\videos\movie.mp4" type=video/mp4; height="240" width="320" autoplay controls></video>`

Appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cant be allowed, imagine you opening a website and it starts playing one of your video files in your computer...

Comment: True, that makes sense. Can u help me with this...I'm trying to record a video and savi it in the database ....how can i do that?? Thank you.

Comment: Record with what? with JavaScript? Im not sure but I dont think its something easy to do. I cant help you more...

Comment: Recording with the help of API, and storing that in the D drive and saving the path in database table...And then trying to extract it from another webpage.

Comment: JavaScript cant store files, for the same reasons it cant read files